# How to check if a String is numeric in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

How can you check if the whole string is a number?

You can check if a string contains a number with regular expression. Can you use regular expressions as well to find out if a string is only a number, without any other characters?

`"abc"` is supposed to be `false`, it's not a number
`"abc12"` is supposed to be `false`, it's not a number
`"123"` is supposed to be `true`

Answer (score 0):

if you are not using variables, and literal which is one quote, exactly what is in between the quotes.

```
'abc' -is [String]

'abc12' -is [String]

'123' -is [String]
```

Comment: I am using variables. I don't want to check if something is a string. Your examples all give true, because they are all strings. I want to check if a string contains only digits.

Comment: You can change to variables on the left hand side, and on the right hand side change the `[String]` to `[Int]`